# How to Join tables without generating a 'combinatorial explosion' - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cartesian-product

I am working on a databse named classicmodels. You can find it at: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx/

This company sells miniatures, which are distributed among 7 product lines: classic cars, vintage cars, planes, trucks & buses, planes, trains and motorcycles.

I want to discover which were the best-selling product lines (in units sold and in revenue) in 2003 and 2004.

Also, I need to exclude orders that were cancelled. This is informed by the 'status' column in the 'orders' table.

So, apparently, we have to join three tables: 'products' (to group the results by each productline), 'orderdetails' (to get the quantity sold and price per unit) and 'orders' (to filter the results: select only 2003 and 2004 and exclude cancelled orders).

In addition, it is relevant to state that we will have to deal with 1:M (one-to-many) pairs to solve this problem, in order to avoid combinatorial/cartesian explosions.

- products --> orderdetails is a 1:M relationship
- orderdetails --> orders is a 1:M relationship

Taking this into account, I decided to create subqueries to establish 1:1 relationships. So, I calculated the quantity ordered and the total value per product line:

```
SELECT p.productLine, SUM(od.quantityOrdered) AS total_units, SUM(od.quantityOrdered*od.PriceEach) AS total_value
FROM products p
    JOIN
orderdetails od ON p.productCode=od.productCode
GROUP BY p.productLine
ORDER BY total_value DESC;
```

The result was the following:

[image]

Now, I don't know how to JOIN the table generated by the subquery above with the 'orders' table. This is due to the fact that they don't have any common columns that could be used in a JOIN.

How can I identify the best-selling product lines (in units sold and in revenue) in 2003 and 2004, excluding cancelled orders?

You can check the database's relational schema below:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output corresponding to that sample data, and share all such information in text form (not as images)

Comment: from your description, you want to join on product line, so do that?

Comment: @NicoHaase Ok! I added the database's relational schema to the post. I am sorry, but what do you mean by sample input data? Also, I don't know how to share the ouput of a MySQL query as text. But I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to join the results that you have on to the `orders` table, you want to do that join ***before*** you aggregate the results.

That's just adding another join to the end of your list of `JOIN`s, then filter with a `WHERE` clause, then aggregate as you already were...

```
SELECT
  p.productLine,
  SUM(od.quantityOrdered) AS total_units,
  SUM(od.quantityOrdered*od.PriceEach) AS total_value
FROM
  products       p
INNER JOIN
  orderdetails   od
    ON p.productCode = od.productCode
INNER JOIN
  orders         o
    ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
WHERE
      o.status    != 'Cancelled'
  AND o.orderDate >= '2003-01-01'
  AND o.orderDate <  '2005-01-01'  -- Less than the next year, in case the date includes a time
GROUP BY
  p.productLine
ORDER BY
  total_value DESC;
```

Comment: I have a quick doubt. AND o.orderDate >= '2003-01-01' AND o.orderDate <  '2005-01-01' are inclusive, right? Do they consider the start and end dates in the calculations? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: `>= '2003-01-01'` is ***in***clusive; which includes everything from the very start of 2003 onwards.  `< '2005-01-01'` is ***ex***clusive; which includes everything *before* 2005, even the very last pico second of 2004 but not including Any of 2005, regardless of data type or data granularity.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another `JOIN` with the `orders` table, and the `WHERE` condition to limit to the orders you want.

```
SELECT p.productLine, SUM(od.quantityOrdered) AS total_units, SUM(od.quantityOrdered*od.PriceEach) AS total_value
FROM products p
JOIN orderdetails od ON p.productCode=od.productCode
JOIN orders o ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
WHERE o.orderDate BETWEEN '2003-01-01' AND '2004-12-31'
    AND o.status != 'cancelled'
GROUP BY p.productLine
ORDER BY total_value DESC;
```

Comment: The 'BETWEEN' operator is inclusive, right? I mean, does it include '2003-01-01' (start date) and '2004-12-31' (end date) in the calculations? Thank you for your help! The solution is very clear!

Comment: Yes, can't you look that up yourself?

Comment: Note that if `orderDate` includes the time, you should use `'2004-12-31 23:59:59'` as the end of the range.

Comment: @ Barmar Ah ok! I didn't know that I had to include the time. However, this is not the case for this database. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you leave out the time it defaults to `00:00:00`, so it would miss the last day.